# Slow code using MSQL, PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm currently trying to learn HTML, AJAX, PHP, and MYSQL. I'm currently building a webapp just for internal use. It al seemed to work but now I'm experiencing some lag in my code using the MYSQL function.

Here's what happens:

First off all, I create some "profile images" form an sql database. trough PHP like this:

```
   <?php
    $price = 30;
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("Og297", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Og297.Drinkers");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $picture = $row['Picture'];
        $name = $row['Name'];
        $nameup= $name."up";
        $namep= $name."p";

        $Onbetaaldresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Betaald) AS ob FROM Og297.Bierlijst
        WHERE Betaald='1' AND Name='$name'");
        $Onbetaaldarray= mysql_fetch_array($Onbetaaldresult);
        $Onbetaald= $Onbetaaldarray['ob'];


        $Betaaldresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Betaald) AS b FROM Og297.Bierlijst
        WHERE Betaald='0' AND Name='$name'");
        $Betaaldarray= mysql_fetch_array($Betaaldresult);
        $Betaald= $Betaaldarray['b'];

    echo "<div onclick=\"addBeer('$name','$price');\" class= 'thumbnail'><img src= $picture height= '90' width= '90' alt= $name title= $name><div class= 'overlay'><span id=$nameup  class='unpaid'>$Onbetaald</span><span id= $namep class='paid'>/$Betaald</span></div></div>";
        }
    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

So this shows for every user a picture div, on top of that it shows to span's with the ID's Paid and Unpaid(The app is for keeping track how much beer we've paid and how much still need to be paid). This all works :)

next I have some functions;

On is addBeer, wich ads a beer into a table, including the name of that person. This is done trough Ajax.

```
function addBeer (n,p)
{
$.post("AddBeer.php",{naam: n, price: p});
updateBeer(n);
}
```

So after having inserted the beer into the datbase, I want it to update the Paid and Unpaid span's. I do this by using updateBeer.

```
function updateBeer (n) 
{
$.post("UpdateBeer.php",{naam: n},function(data) {
changeInfo(n,data.betaald,data.onbetaald);
},"json");
}
```

This returns the amount of paid and unpaid in a Json object. Those values(including the name of the person are then given to changeInfo function, wich will update the span's like this:

```
function changeInfo(n,b,ob)
{
window.alert("ja");
document.getElementById(n + "up").innerHTML=ob;
document.getElementById(n + "p").innerHTML="/" + b;
}
```

However, the info is not updated every time I click an image.. It lags behind, the beers are inserted tough, but the updating of the span's is just not happening. How come?

Thanks very much for even reading this huge question!

Comment: `window.alert("ja");` is executed with a delay?

Comment: it was just there for testing purposes. Removing it doesn't help..

Comment: Removing it shouldn't have any effect. I was just trying to understand which function was taking longer.

Comment: Alright, uhm lets see. I have now done this:
     function changeInfo(n,b,ob)
     {
     window.alert(b + ob);}
It seems that the function is executed before the AJAX request finishes in addBeer. Could this be true?

Comment: The call to `$.post` here is asynchronous, so it will return before the actual execution is complete.

Comment: Alright that's what I tought. Is it a good idea to set assync to false?

Comment: You could set it to false. In these cases, when waiting for data to return from server, you could use a `Loading...` modal spinner to give the user some visual feedback of the activity.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you very much Chtulhu! You can answer my question if you like!

Comment: You can answer your own question better I think. :)

Comment: and that's actually a common practice at stackoverflow, it helping not to waste time on questions that have been answered already. some unrelated link - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my code was that the AJAX request where async. Thus causing problems when the rest of the script was executed before the AJAX request was completed. The trick was to set the AJAX request to set Async to false!

Thanks!